# Adjusting width between image and label in RibbonMenuItem

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control

I'm having some difficulty with styling the RibbonMenuButton in [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF (October 2010)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877).

Is there any way in which I can access the property for the width between the image and the label? I can't find any relevant member on the [MSDN Property List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonmenuitem_properties.aspx), and as expected, adjusting the padding just changes the spacing between the entire button and it's container.

```
<ribbon:RibbonMenuButton SmallImageSource="/MyProject;component/Images/Foo.png" Label=Bar">
    ...
</ribbon:RibbonMenuButton>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will likely have to be done through the template.  For template manipulation, I typically use Expression Blend as it allows easier access to the template and provides design time display of an example of the item being templated.  If you don't have it, [**pick up a trial**](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/).

If you do get it, load your solution into Blend, right-click on an item you want to change the template for, selected Edit Template > Edit a Copy...

The template will be copied, referenced by the item, and you can then edit it to suit the look and feel you want for the control.